# How to convert base64 string to blob?

Tags: java, android, base64, arrays, blob

A Synchronization service that provide an image in `Base64` string and I want to save that into a `SQLite` database `blob` field?

Could anyone tell me how to proceed with this or any other way to do this procedure?

As later on, I need to show image in bitmap.

Comment: convert base64 to bitmap  then bit map to Byte[], this Byte[] to Db.make sure your column name have type with blob

Comment: Have a loot at http://wiki.lenux.org/base64-string-to-blob-object/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You convert a base64 image string to byte[] like :**

```
byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(yourBase64String, 0);
```

**after that you also can convert it to Bitmap :**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
```

Comment: I think we should update:
`byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decoder.decode(yourBase64String, 0); `

Comment: how is "yourBase64String" look like? is it possible "137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0..."

Comment: I think we should update: `byte[] decodedByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(yourBase64String);`

Answer (score 2):

To convert a base64 string to a byte[], you can use:

```
byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(yourBase64String)
```

And to convert a byte[] to a blob, you can use:

```
Blob b = new SerialBlob(decodedByte);
```